# Nichrome Wire No Heating with 9V

Tags: heat

I have tried connecting one feet of Nichrome 80 wire ( 22 g ) with a 9V battery. Is this enough to heat the wire?

Comment: It is possible most of the heat is being dissipated inside the battery (internal resistance).

Comment: Thanks.. Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: I'm with @WesleyLee. My measurements of a fresh 9V battery shows internal resistance of about two ohms. Your 1ft resistance wire has one ohm. As the battery ages, its resistance goes up. You should likely use a more robust source of current.

Comment: Get a current source with higher current output: Bunch of AA batteries in parallel, for example. You can use bench power supplies and etc, but be careful to not short random power supplies - i.e. use the Constat Current setting (current limit).

Comment: To what degree (pun intended) do you want to heat the wire? Any source of current will heat the wire, but how warm it gets it depends...

Comment: Be aware for your future projects that traditional 9v batteries have abysmal performance for what they are and a high cost.  They should be used only to achieve a necessary form factor or longevity with low current loads.  For disposable batteries, AA and AAA and sometimes larger cylindrical cells tend to have best performance and cost effect.  NiMH will tend to improve cost effect at the cost of compatibility (not all devices run well at the lower voltage) and Li-Ion rechargeables will probably give best cost effect at the expense of greater danger and the most complicated charging circuit.

Answer (score 2):

A really good 9V battery can supply a few watts and might have an available specification that would give better guidance to designing your heater. If the wire is too long, too little current will be allowed to flow and the wire won't produce very much heat. If it's too short, then too much current will flow, and the battery will heat up more than the wire. If you have a multimeter, you should ensure the output of the battery is near 9V and see if the current through the wire is near 1A. If memory serves that's close to the optimum you will see from a 9V.